# Android bottom navigation appears when pressing on Flutter bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);`
to only display the top system overlay (Where you normally see time and notifications) and disable bottom navigation of the device (3 buttons in android or slider in IOS).

Problem is that when I try to press the Bottom Navigation Bar of my Flutter application, it automatically activates the bottom bar of the system, blocking out the bottom navigation bar of the app.

Resizing the app is not suitable for me. I don't want this to happen, and system navigation should only appear when user slides from the bottom.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you share your code so that I can have a better Idea,

```
// to hide only bottom bar:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

// to hide only status bar: 
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

// to hide both:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);

//to bring them back:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)
```

Implement the in your code and it should work.